# Decoding JSON data

Tags: perl, json

This is my Perl program

```
package ABCD;
use base qw/JSON::XS/;

my $json = '{"alphabet" : ["a:1", "b:2", "c:3", "d:4"],"number" : ["1:a","2:b"]}';
my $decoded = decode_json($json);
```

When I am executing this I am getting an error like

> Undefined subroutine `&test::decode_json` called at test.pm line 4, `<STDIN>` line 1.

Comment: Why are you trying to subclass `JSON::XS` instead of simply using it?

Comment: I understand why you made this mistake, but I need a bit of context in order to write a good explanation. (1) Have just started learning Perl? If so: what resources are you using (e.g. what book or online tutorial)? (2) Do you know other languages like PHP, Ruby or Java? If you tell me what language you already know, I can explain in terms of that language.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to run:

```
use JSON::XS;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json = '{"alphabet" : ["a:1", "b:2", "c:3", "d:4"],"number" : ["1:a","2:b"]}';
my $decoded = decode_json($json);
print Dumper($json,$decoded);
```